# sessions lost in php / linux centos

Tags: php, linux, session, centos

Ok. I know there are lot of posts regarding lost sessions navigating between pages, but none of them is like the following:

I'm working on a site that in the shared hosting account works well.

When I moved the site to a cloud server I could only login. But when I was in, any action on any page threw out the user versus the login page, with not session variables anymore somewhere.

Everything was fine for me, the session path was writable, the sessions were correctly settled and till the first page the sessions were dispayed correctly at the begin and and the end of the html code.

After 1 day going crazy I discovered that for every single error in a page (css file not found or image not found) the session got lost. So, one, by one, I correct those errors (wich is very good by the way) and now the site is working again.

My question is where I can configure a linux server behaviour such these, saving and writing sessions even if there is some error in the programming?

I would like to know it because if the shared hosting works like that, means that somewhere there is a directive to do that... an I can't find anything till now.

Comment: What your problem now? session working or not?

Comment: Now yes. But I had to fix all "little" html errors, like images not correctly referenced or missing .css files... in any case, the question was if some one knows the reason for such different behaviour  between servers...

Comment: I think you couldn't install it properly. Was there any installation docs?

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility for an error to cause a session not to be saved (assuming you use the normal session save handlers) is that PHP itself would crash before the end of the page - all other cases (an error unrelated to PHP such as a missing CSS file or image or a PHP error which is not a crash) should still have PHP go through normal shutdown where `session_write_close()` is automatically performed if you did not manually do it before.

It is also unlikely that this is a Linux related issue.

The most probable option would be some difference in the PHP session settings between your old hosting and new server. Run `phpinfo()` on both and compare the session settings - see if you find anything unusual.

Also, I would suggest making sure that your session ID cookie gets accepted by the browser and does not change over time. Use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to track the value of the session ID cookie (called PHPSESSID by default) through several pages. Make sure it is accepted by the browser and does not change all the time.

Comment: I think is interesting what you say about the php crash. In any case I tested all the things you said, and the only differences between the two ini's were: session.bug_compat_warn (SHARED HOSTING: On CLOUD SERVER: Off) session.save_path (but it was correctly settled) Registered save handlers (SHARED HOSTING: files user sqlite CLOUD SERVER: files user) and Registered serializer handlers (SHARED HOSTING: files user sqlite CLOUD SERVER: php php_binary wddx)

Comment: None of these differences seem like they could cause such a problem. 
Did you check for possible cookie value changes? I suggest also checking that your browser actually *sends the cookie back* - if not, it could indicate that somehow an invalid cookie is being created.

Answer (score 0):

If any of those errors caused errors or warnings to be displayed on the page, before the session was started, then it makes sense because any output blocks you from starting a session.